# How can I recreate CrystalDiskMark's disk benchmark on Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, performance, benchmarking

I want to be able to test the read/write performance of my disks on Windows and in Linux, and get as accurate a comparison as possible.

On Windows I'm using CrystalDiskMark, because hey, it's OSS and everyone else uses it...

So I want to run *the same benchmark* on Linux, but CrystalDiskMark is Windows only.

#### So the question is, how would I go about getting the closest possible equivalent of the CrystalDiskMark results on Linux?

---

I've taken a stab at this myself, but I'm nowhere near qualified to say if this is an accurate comparison.

Here is the CrystalDiskMark result from a Windows VM on my PC:

[image: Screenshot]

That's pretty terrible.

Here is my attempt at recreating the same benchmark on the Linux host:

```
➜ fio --loops=5 --size=1000m --filename=/home/tomas/disktest.tmp --stonewall --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --group_reporting \
        --name=Seq-Q32-Read --bs=1m --iodepth=32 --numjobs=1 --rw=read \
        --name=Seq-Q32-Write --bs=1m --iodepth=32 --numjobs=1 --rw=write \
        --name=4KiB-Q8-Read --bs=4k --iodepth=8 --numjobs=8 --rw=randread \
        --name=4KiB-Q8-Write --bs=4k --iodepth=8 --numjobs=8 --rw=randwrite \
        --name=4KiB-Q32-Read --bs=4k --iodepth=32 --numjobs=1 --rw=randread \
        --name=4KiB-Q32-Write --bs=4k --iodepth=32 --numjobs=1 --rw=randwrite \
        --name=4KiB-Q1-Read --bs=4k --iodepth=1 --numjobs=1 --rw=randread \
        --name=4KiB-Q1-Write --bs=4k --iodepth=1 --numjobs=1 --rw=randwrite

Seq-Q32-Read: (g=0): rw=read, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
Seq-Q32-Write: (g=1): rw=write, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
4KiB-Q8-Read: (g=2): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=8
...
4KiB-Q8-Write: (g=3): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=8
...
4KiB-Q32-Read: (g=4): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
4KiB-Q32-Write: (g=5): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=32
4KiB-Q1-Read: (g=6): rw=randread, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=1
4KiB-Q1-Write: (g=7): rw=randwrite, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=1
fio-3.19
Starting 22 processes
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [_(21),w(1)][100.0%][w=304MiB/s][w=77.7k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]                       
Seq-Q32-Read: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152468: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  read: IOPS=8143, BW=8143MiB/s (8539MB/s)(5000MiB/614msec)
    slat (usec): min=15, max=209, avg=18.86, stdev=11.40
    clat (usec): min=535, max=7497, avg=3882.28, stdev=581.71
     lat (usec): min=553, max=7517, avg=3901.21, stdev=580.07
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[ 1483],  5.00th=[ 3326], 10.00th=[ 3490], 20.00th=[ 3589],
     | 30.00th=[ 3687], 40.00th=[ 3785], 50.00th=[ 3851], 60.00th=[ 3949],
     | 70.00th=[ 4047], 80.00th=[ 4178], 90.00th=[ 4359], 95.00th=[ 4621],
     | 99.00th=[ 6128], 99.50th=[ 6652], 99.90th=[ 7242], 99.95th=[ 7308],
     | 99.99th=[ 7504]
  lat (usec)   : 750=0.22%, 1000=0.26%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.90%, 4=64.36%, 10=34.26%
  cpu          : usr=0.49%, sys=15.99%, ctx=4878, majf=0, minf=8203
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.2%, 4=0.4%, 8=0.8%, 16=1.6%, 32=96.9%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=99.9%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=5000,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32
Seq-Q32-Write: (groupid=1, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152476: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  write: IOPS=8561, BW=8562MiB/s (8978MB/s)(5000MiB/584msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=20, max=252, avg=37.24, stdev= 8.51
    clat (usec): min=1042, max=7200, avg=3674.07, stdev=787.35
     lat (usec): min=1080, max=7235, avg=3711.41, stdev=787.63
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[ 1156],  5.00th=[ 3392], 10.00th=[ 3458], 20.00th=[ 3490],
     | 30.00th=[ 3490], 40.00th=[ 3523], 50.00th=[ 3556], 60.00th=[ 3556],
     | 70.00th=[ 3589], 80.00th=[ 3621], 90.00th=[ 3949], 95.00th=[ 5211],
     | 99.00th=[ 6980], 99.50th=[ 6980], 99.90th=[ 7177], 99.95th=[ 7177],
     | 99.99th=[ 7177]
  lat (msec)   : 2=2.06%, 4=89.38%, 10=8.56%
  cpu          : usr=17.32%, sys=16.64%, ctx=4993, majf=0, minf=13
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.2%, 4=0.4%, 8=0.8%, 16=1.6%, 32=96.9%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=99.9%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,5000,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32
4KiB-Q8-Read: (groupid=2, jobs=8): err= 0: pid=152477: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  read: IOPS=688k, BW=2689MiB/s (2819MB/s)(39.1GiB/14877msec)
    slat (nsec): min=1920, max=1768.7k, avg=3175.67, stdev=2519.59
    clat (usec): min=12, max=4979, avg=89.03, stdev=27.34
     lat (usec): min=15, max=4982, avg=92.28, stdev=27.45
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   64],  5.00th=[   68], 10.00th=[   70], 20.00th=[   73],
     | 30.00th=[   77], 40.00th=[   80], 50.00th=[   84], 60.00th=[   89],
     | 70.00th=[   94], 80.00th=[  102], 90.00th=[  117], 95.00th=[  129],
     | 99.00th=[  159], 99.50th=[  176], 99.90th=[  253], 99.95th=[  379],
     | 99.99th=[  635]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 2393, max= 2761, per=100.00%, avg=2700.80, stdev=10.83, samples=232
   iops        : min=612654, max=706936, avg=691405.41, stdev=2772.56, samples=232
  lat (usec)   : 20=0.01%, 50=0.01%, 100=78.31%, 250=21.58%, 500=0.07%
  lat (usec)   : 750=0.03%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=6.76%, sys=29.86%, ctx=5989610, majf=0, minf=177
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=100.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=10240000,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=8
4KiB-Q8-Write: (groupid=3, jobs=8): err= 0: pid=152521: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  write: IOPS=1400k, BW=5469MiB/s (5735MB/s)(39.1GiB/7314msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=2, max=6681, avg= 4.16, stdev= 7.43
    clat (nsec): min=1020, max=10186k, avg=38309.07, stdev=80059.95
     lat (usec): min=9, max=10188, avg=42.55, stdev=80.56
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   21],  5.00th=[   26], 10.00th=[   28], 20.00th=[   29],
     | 30.00th=[   30], 40.00th=[   31], 50.00th=[   33], 60.00th=[   35],
     | 70.00th=[   37], 80.00th=[   41], 90.00th=[   49], 95.00th=[   59],
     | 99.00th=[   94], 99.50th=[  135], 99.90th=[  441], 99.95th=[ 2737],
     | 99.99th=[ 2966]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 4578, max= 6979, per=100.00%, avg=5820.14, stdev=98.27, samples=106
   iops        : min=1172017, max=1786792, avg=1489955.57, stdev=25158.07, samples=106
  lat (usec)   : 2=0.01%, 10=0.03%, 20=0.93%, 50=89.82%, 100=8.35%
  lat (usec)   : 250=0.72%, 500=0.07%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.06%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=12.76%, sys=73.25%, ctx=1495680, majf=0, minf=125
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=100.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,10240000,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=8
4KiB-Q32-Read: (groupid=4, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152543: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  read: IOPS=304k, BW=1189MiB/s (1247MB/s)(5000MiB/4205msec)
    slat (nsec): min=1890, max=62518, avg=2524.61, stdev=728.21
    clat (usec): min=58, max=6518, avg=102.21, stdev=36.00
     lat (usec): min=61, max=6523, avg=104.80, stdev=36.05
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   78],  5.00th=[   85], 10.00th=[   88], 20.00th=[   91],
     | 30.00th=[   95], 40.00th=[   98], 50.00th=[  101], 60.00th=[  104],
     | 70.00th=[  106], 80.00th=[  111], 90.00th=[  117], 95.00th=[  127],
     | 99.00th=[  149], 99.50th=[  161], 99.90th=[  289], 99.95th=[  388],
     | 99.99th=[  619]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 1106, max= 1281, per=100.00%, avg=1195.44, stdev=74.58, samples=7
   iops        : min=283374, max=327936, avg=306032.57, stdev=19092.48, samples=7
  lat (usec)   : 100=48.13%, 250=51.72%, 500=0.11%, 750=0.03%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 10=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=18.79%, sys=73.53%, ctx=10748, majf=0, minf=44
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=1280000,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32
4KiB-Q32-Write: (groupid=5, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152553: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  write: IOPS=260k, BW=1014MiB/s (1064MB/s)(5000MiB/4929msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=2, max=1292, avg= 3.07, stdev= 3.99
    clat (nsec): min=1169, max=3440.3k, avg=119726.11, stdev=38202.94
     lat (usec): min=9, max=3444, avg=122.86, stdev=38.61
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   95],  5.00th=[   99], 10.00th=[  101], 20.00th=[  103],
     | 30.00th=[  105], 40.00th=[  108], 50.00th=[  110], 60.00th=[  115],
     | 70.00th=[  127], 80.00th=[  135], 90.00th=[  141], 95.00th=[  153],
     | 99.00th=[  241], 99.50th=[  285], 99.90th=[  494], 99.95th=[  685],
     | 99.99th=[ 1287]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=972616, max=1133568, per=99.61%, avg=1034652.00, stdev=55377.49, samples=9
   iops        : min=243154, max=283392, avg=258663.22, stdev=13844.19, samples=9
  lat (usec)   : 2=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 20=0.06%, 50=0.18%, 100=6.51%
  lat (usec)   : 250=92.41%, 500=0.74%, 750=0.06%, 1000=0.02%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=16.66%, sys=75.67%, ctx=144022, majf=0, minf=15
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.1%, 32=100.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.1%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,1280000,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=32
4KiB-Q1-Read: (groupid=6, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152562: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  read: IOPS=15.4k, BW=60.1MiB/s (63.0MB/s)(5000MiB/83174msec)
    slat (nsec): min=2080, max=26179, avg=2459.69, stdev=530.83
    clat (usec): min=5, max=70982, avg=62.10, stdev=63.77
     lat (usec): min=8, max=70985, avg=64.62, stdev=63.77
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[   59],  5.00th=[   60], 10.00th=[   61], 20.00th=[   61],
     | 30.00th=[   62], 40.00th=[   62], 50.00th=[   62], 60.00th=[   63],
     | 70.00th=[   63], 80.00th=[   64], 90.00th=[   64], 95.00th=[   65],
     | 99.00th=[   67], 99.50th=[   68], 99.90th=[  139], 99.95th=[  229],
     | 99.99th=[  461]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=59920, max=62672, per=100.00%, avg=61700.32, stdev=396.46, samples=165
   iops        : min=14980, max=15668, avg=15425.08, stdev=99.12, samples=165
  lat (usec)   : 10=0.04%, 20=0.02%, 50=0.01%, 100=99.78%, 250=0.11%
  lat (usec)   : 500=0.04%, 750=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%, 100=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=1.26%, sys=4.78%, ctx=1280023, majf=0, minf=15
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=1280000,0,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1
4KiB-Q1-Write: (groupid=7, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=152734: Mon May  4 19:59:09 2020
  write: IOPS=78.8k, BW=308MiB/s (323MB/s)(5000MiB/16249msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (nsec): min=2210, max=21549, avg=2459.24, stdev=272.82
    clat (nsec): min=360, max=4257.7k, avg=9833.56, stdev=6903.88
     lat (usec): min=10, max=4260, avg=12.35, stdev= 6.92
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[    8],  5.00th=[    8], 10.00th=[    8], 20.00th=[    9],
     | 30.00th=[    9], 40.00th=[   11], 50.00th=[   11], 60.00th=[   11],
     | 70.00th=[   11], 80.00th=[   11], 90.00th=[   11], 95.00th=[   12],
     | 99.00th=[   13], 99.50th=[   14], 99.90th=[   17], 99.95th=[   20],
     | 99.99th=[  133]
   bw (  KiB/s): min=310086, max=321632, per=100.00%, avg=315613.19, stdev=2609.60, samples=32
   iops        : min=77521, max=80408, avg=78903.28, stdev=652.43, samples=32
  lat (nsec)   : 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%
  lat (usec)   : 4=0.01%, 10=32.92%, 20=67.03%, 50=0.02%, 100=0.01%
  lat (usec)   : 250=0.01%, 500=0.01%, 1000=0.01%
  lat (msec)   : 2=0.01%, 4=0.01%, 10=0.01%
  cpu          : usr=6.50%, sys=25.87%, ctx=1280022, majf=0, minf=14
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,1280000,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=8143MiB/s (8539MB/s), 8143MiB/s-8143MiB/s (8539MB/s-8539MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=614-614msec

Run status group 1 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=8562MiB/s (8978MB/s), 8562MiB/s-8562MiB/s (8978MB/s-8978MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=584-584msec

Run status group 2 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=2689MiB/s (2819MB/s), 2689MiB/s-2689MiB/s (2819MB/s-2819MB/s), io=39.1GiB (41.9GB), run=14877-14877msec

Run status group 3 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=5469MiB/s (5735MB/s), 5469MiB/s-5469MiB/s (5735MB/s-5735MB/s), io=39.1GiB (41.9GB), run=7314-7314msec

Run status group 4 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=1189MiB/s (1247MB/s), 1189MiB/s-1189MiB/s (1247MB/s-1247MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=4205-4205msec

Run status group 5 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=1014MiB/s (1064MB/s), 1014MiB/s-1014MiB/s (1064MB/s-1064MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=4929-4929msec

Run status group 6 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=60.1MiB/s (63.0MB/s), 60.1MiB/s-60.1MiB/s (63.0MB/s-63.0MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=83174-83174msec

Run status group 7 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=308MiB/s (323MB/s), 308MiB/s-308MiB/s (323MB/s-323MB/s), io=5000MiB (5243MB), run=16249-16249msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    dm-4: ios=12805000/12795016, merge=0/0, ticks=1073203/182228, in_queue=1255557, util=98.33%, aggrios=12840923/12850350, aggrmerge=0/0, aggrticks=0/0, aggrin_queue=0, aggrutil=0.00%
    md0: ios=12840923/12850350, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%, aggrios=4280230/4283484, aggrmerge=77/475, aggrticks=398850/90297, aggrin_queue=45665, aggrutil=98.31%
  nvme1n1: ios=4280757/4283635, merge=82/428, ticks=398406/100042, in_queue=49090, util=98.30%
  nvme0n1: ios=4274346/4278171, merge=80/489, ticks=395498/78447, in_queue=31827, util=98.31%
  nvme2n1: ios=4285589/4288647, merge=69/510, ticks=402648/92403, in_queue=56080, util=98.30%
```

But I am not sure if all the options I'm using are equivalent to the settings CrystalDiskMark uses. In particular I have no idea if `--jobs` is equivalent to the thread count in CrystalDiskMark.

The point of this exercise (for me) is to try to figure out which virtual disk technology will have the least performance impact, but to do that I need to be able to run the same benchmark on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com. :)

Answer (score 0):

(fio doesn't have a `--jobs` option so I assume you meant --numjobs? It may also be kind to reference the original question over on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93791/109111 ...)

The thing I never liked about the CrystalDiskMark style jobs is that the region the I/O is done over is very small (1GByte). For your fio job on your Linux host, I don't know which filesystem you are using so it might still be doing caching (`direct=1` sets `O_DIRECT` which is a hint not an order). I say this because some of your numbers look high - can your disk really do 5 Giga**bytes** of I/O per second (I don't know your setup)? If you have the option, do I/O that is at least twice the size of your memory to reduce the impact of any caching that may be happening.

> In particular I have no idea if --jobs is equivalent to the thread count in CrystalDiskMark.

I suppose if you want to ensure fio uses threads you can add `--thread` to the global options of your command line but that's a minor tweak and I'd be surprised if it moves the needle much in this case. But generally, when I wrote my original answer the intent was for `numjobs` to replicate the thread count reported by CrystalDiskMark.

I think the fio job descriptions were based off reading one of the manual pages (https://web.archive.org/web/20170204232147/https://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/manual-en/MainWindow.html ?) and mentally converting the DiskSpd (https://github.com/microsoft/diskspd ) job description to fio job descriptions. If you check [fio parameter documentation](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#job-file-parameters) and the [DiskSpd command line docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/diskspd/wiki/Command-line-and-parameters) you can see what the different options do...

> The point of this exercise (for me) is to try to figure out which virtual disk technology will have the least performance impact, but to do that I need to be able to run the same benchmark on both Windows and Linux.

There are differences between Windows and Linux and there are lots of layers in your comparison. Certain behaviours don't have an easy one-to-one mapping (e.g. fio can easily use processes or threads on Linux while on Windows DiskSpd currently does more optimal filesystem layout than fio does when in its Windows port). The other thing to do is look at the output of `iostat` command on the Linux host while you're doing I/O so you can see what's coming out of the bottom in both cases. Good luck!

Comment: I have three Corsair MP510 960GB in raid-0, so the numbers aren't necessarily unrealistic. That test was run on a file on ext4 on a LVM volume, if that matters. I was indeed talking about `--numjobs`, as shown in the example. Also I didn't mean to plagiarize the original question, I simply forgot that's where I got the command from, I've had it laying around in my notes for quite a while :P Thanks for the answer.